# Mxnet MMS - Access from external server

Tags: curl, server, deep-learning, mxnet, mms

I am trying to use Mxnet MMS (multi-model-server) to make my Mxnet model accessible by my website. The Mxnet MMS can run without problem and I can use the served model on the same machine. However, I want to access the served model from another server that are connected each other through the LAN. In order to test the connection, I run the following command from the terminal of Server A (assume that Mxnet MMS works on Server B). When I try to access it, I get an error.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/hand -T image.jpg
```

Although the above command runs without problem when I try to run this command in the same server, it does not work from the another server. In order to perform this, how could I do to access the served model on another server?

I also tried to use IP address instead of a localhost. However, it gives below error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to $IP_address$ port 8080: Connection
> refused

Could anyone help?

Thanks and best.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about `PORT` and I solved the problem using `SSH` connection as below:

```
sshpass -p $your_password$ ssh $your_username$@$server$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/hand -T image.jpg
```

Additionally, you can open SSH connection outside of the `curl` command for one time.

Note: If you have any other suggestion, please edit my message or post another answer/comment to inform me and other users. Thank you.